# JS Object property returns 'NaN' on passing expression

Tags: javascript, object

I want to assign property age to the object and I know it can be done using a function like:

```
var john = {
         firstName: "John",
         lastName: "Smith",
         job: "Teacher",
         yearOfBirth: 1990,
         family: ['Jane', 'Mark', 'Bob'],
         calculateAge: function() {
            this.age = 2018 - this.yearOfBirth
         }
      }             

   john.calculateAge();
```

It adds property age into the object John as expected. But can it be done without a function?

When I tried to do like following:

```
var john = {
             firstName: "John",
             lastName: "Smith",
             job: "Teacher",
             yearOfBirth: 1990,
             family: ['Jane', 'Mark', 'Bob'],
             age: 2018 - this.yearOfBirth
          }
```

"age" property returns "NaN". I don't know why it is not returning a number. Is it regular behavior (if 'yes', then why?) or am I doing something wrong over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get any value from an object that has not been finished being declared yet. At the time you write `age: 2018 - this.yearOfBirth`, `var john` is not defined (and even if it was, the calling context would be suspect - might be the global object, might be `undefined`).

Assign the `age` property after the initial object declaration instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of:

```
calculateAge: function() {
 this.age = 2018 - this.yearOfBirth
}

john.calculateAge();
```

the `this`  referes to `john` because `calculateAge`  is called on `john`

For the first code:

```
age: 2018 - this.yearOfBirth
```

`this` refers to the current context in which you create the `john`  object.

You would need to write it that way:

```
var john = {
   firstName: "John",
   lastName: "Smith",
   job: "Teacher",
   yearOfBirth: 1990,
   family: ['Jane', 'Mark', 'Bob']
} 

john.age = 2018 - john.yearOfBirth
```

Answer (score 1):

On :

```
var john = {
             firstName: "John",
             lastName: "Smith",
             job: "Teacher",
             yearOfBirth: 1990,
             family: ['Jane', 'Mark', 'Bob'],
             age: 2018 - this.yearOfBirth
          }
```

`this` isn't refering to your object at this position and `john` isn't yet declared.

You can use this approach below to define `age` attribute when `john` exists :

```js
var john = {
             firstName: "John",
             lastName: "Smith",
             job: "Teacher",
             yearOfBirth: 1990,
             family: ['Jane', 'Mark', 'Bob'],
          };        
          john.age = 2018 - john.yearOfBirth;
          
          console.log(john.age);
```